# Troubleshooting Joomla 3.3.4 Cache

Tags: php, caching, joomla, memcached, xcache

This is the first time I've had this problem with Joomla cache on v3.3.4. What issues I'm having is when I enable cache under Joomla configuration either with conservative or progressive caching using "file", "apc" or "memcache" I keep getting the same results when I load my pages I start losing display modules then I loss the home page scrolling, so if you were to try scrolling down you can't scroll. This usually happens 2 to 5 minutes after you enable cache. I don't have "Joomla - Cache" or "Jotcache" enabled to get this situation.

It's very frustrating because I've run out of check list.

1. If I disable and clear cache I get everything back.
2. I checked all folder properties for right, all correct.
3. I've tried xcache, memcache, memcached and apc but issue still exists.
4. I installed from a previous backup and still nothing
5. I check php open_basedir for restrictions but it's setup correct.
6. I have all settings and configuration as specified from Joomla documenation
7. I've browsed with ipad, iphone and PC firefox, chrome, opera and same issue on all
8. When I tested cache with memcache, apc, xcache I uninstalled memory cache method as listed "memcache, apc, xcache" to avoid cache conflicts.
9. I did read everything I found from internet searches and nothing has resolved this issue.
10. I've even monitored cache and checked each file for issues thinking it might be php memory_limits with watch -n 2 ls -ahl and found nothing.
11. The template is compatible and working correctly without cache.
12. When I turn cache off completely it continues caching for about 5 minutes then I can clear cache and I get scrolling and modules back.
13. I do have sh404sef which is caching URLs and I've disabled/uninstall sh404sef without fixing issue.
14. I disable modules one by one to figure out the problem of cache but still nothing.
15. I have checked logs but on apache, php, and other daemon logs but no errors
16. Apache is v2 and running php5-fpm
17. I have RSFirewall installed but uninstalled and even disabled and still having cache issue.
18. I do have system cache plugins disabled during these tests so it's not assignments to end of system-cache plugins.
19. I have tried different modules and plugin assignments in Joomla but still nothing
20. I don't have any other cache plugins during my testing.
21. All cache plugins have been disabled during my tests.

The only thing I can think of is when the cache re-writes during a refresh it doesn't correctly write the data to cache again.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm thinking this might be caused by insufficient memory with php and php5-fpm?  Possible? I have php.ini with 256M. Seems like enough or maybe system is consuming to much memory?

Comment: This question is about Joomla hosting, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I've tried that already but they have no idea what the issue is so thought I would try stackoverflow because you guys respond better. No one else can figure this out yet. Been trying to resolve it since v3.3.4 for about two weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the template issued - Template has scrolling effects for Jomsocial which needs to be disabled but not documented in Joomla template. The non-scrolling pages resolved the caching issues as well.

Problem resolved.